# Implementing \textbf{} in a Latex custom template

Tags: latex

My `\textbf{}` doesn't works as supposed.
I'm using a custom template (.cls) of my university. The header of my document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[color, ddc]{tudbook}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Is there like some packages I have to add to the class to solve the problem?

Comment: Please add the complete code (as small as possible, but it should show the error / problem you have)